# What is the difference between application server and web server?

Tags: webserver, terminology, application-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between application server and web server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936197/what-is-the-difference-between-application-server-and-web-server)

What is the difference between application server and web server?