# Is Tomcat an HTTP server or a Servlet container?

Tags: apache, http, tomcat, servlets

When I downloaded Apache Tomcat it seem to be both an HTTP server and a Servlet container.
Can I use Apache Tomcat with a different HTTP server than the one built-in in Tomcat ?

Answer (score 4):

At tomcat webpage there is:

> The Apache Tomcat® software is an open source implementation of the Java Servlet, JavaServer Pages, Java Expression Language and Java WebSocket technologies

So yes, it is a servlet container as well. Generally, HTTP Server is just a server, that handles http requests (GET/POST/DELETE/PUT and some others rarely used). With pure http server, you couldn't run any servlet or jsp script.

I have no idea, how to replace the http server by a different one, but this documentation may be helpful for you - how it works together with appache http server.

https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/apache.html

Answer (score 2):

Generally,a program that accepts incoming HTTP connections is called a web server. In that case Apache Tomcat is a web server as it supports HTTP protocol and it is also a web container as it supports Java server pages (JSP)/Servlet, Application programming interfaces(APIs) as well.

Tomcat doesn’t include the typical features of a web server,where the Apache manages the static data of the web pages,redirection etc whereas tomcat manages the web application.

N.B.:- This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12689910/difference-between-web-server-web-container-and-application-server) will enlighten you about the ***basic concepts of web server, web container and application server!***