# servlet container vs app server - in commercial use

Tags: java, application-server, servlet-container

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/5039371/769384, which clearly states the difference between servlet containers and app servers, it seems that a web container such as Tomcat should not be widely used in enterprise applications.

Lots of libraries would have to be installed additionally, so it's a lot easier to install an app server that provides it.

The question is - do I get it right? Are there any enterprise applications run on tomcat? What would be the benefit of deploying a Java EE (EJB+JPA+JSF+...) on a Tomcat instead of a GlassFish server?

Comment: If you've got a clarification question on such a specialized level, please keep it first to a comment on the other question or other answer (whichever is more appropriate) and train in patience. Otherwise if you want to create a new question, make it self-contained, see as well http://sscce.org/ . it's just that others reading that other question have other understanding if you ask like you just did, it's not that clear what this is all about (and specifically how it fits on this Q&A site here about programming).

Comment: IMHO it covers a different topic than the topic I refer to. Otherwise, referring to other topics could have been oficially banned all over stackoverflow :/

Comment: lol, nope, that's not what I was concerned about. the problem is that you have a very well understanding what you ask about, however, just by reading your question it's not clear. You're asking an understanding quesiton. Only those persons here who have the exact same understanding problem will be able to help you, which can be problematic because normally technical problems related questions (not understanding problem related questions) are on-topic. You might be able to convert the question from the one domain to the other and it can be reopened IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Servlet containers which can be also called web containers don't support EJBs', they only support Servlets and JSPs' along with other related technologies.

If you need to deploy and EJB, you'll then need an application server.

Comment: Yes, I know. That's the point - you can deploy only JSP and servlets on tomcat, that's not much as for JEE apps, is it? I just don't get why is tomcat so popular if it's so limited.

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz it depends what you mean by "limited" - you can write very capable apps without EJBs etc. using frameworks such as Spring MVC or Grails.