# Difference between implementing Web Service using Stateless Session Bean and without it

Tags: java, web-services

I am trying to learn how to use Web Services. I have been reading [this link](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html), but I don't understand the difference between Implement and Not Implement Web Service as a Stateless Session Bean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`@Stateless`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Stateless.html) annotation turns the POJO into an [EJB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/ejb/index.html) and it gives all the [EJB features](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnblr.html).

The big difference is that EJBs runs in a full featured Java EE 5+ Web Application Server like GlassFish or JBoss, making it unusable in a Servlet Container like Tomcat or Jetty.

More info:

- [Difference between an application server and a servlet container?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5039354/1065197)
- [Web Server Vs Servlet Container Vs Application Server](http://www.ecomputercoach.com/index.php/component/content/article/68-servers/72-web-server-vs-servlet-container-vs-application-server.html)