# Java 15: Make a Maven Project of jaxws using tomcat10 embedded

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I try to make a java 15 maven project of a jaxws webservice using a embedded tomcat 10.
My current project is on https://github.com/BeRoots/MeteoWS/tree/master/src/main/java

I'm not sure it's a good idea to make this project using the cargo-maven2-plugin instead of building this project from an Axis2 or CXF Java-First SOAP archtype. But I want to preserve this way if it's acceptable. More informations about this choice are welcome ;)

To explain my actual problem. I have an error when I run maven:build with the error:

> SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/servlet/ServletContextAttributeListener

If someone have an idea. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

We just faced the same problem and the solution was adding `jakarta.servlet-api` to the project:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searchs. I finally find a good answer about server uses. It explain that tomcat isn't a good server for this kind of project.

[Difference between an application server and a servlet container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039354/difference-between-an-application-server-and-a-servlet-container)
and
[enter link description here](https://ducmanhphan.github.io/2020-04-01-The-difference-between-web-server-web-container-application-server/)
So I choose to abord this maven project type to recreate a new one using glassfish.