# three -tier architectures with JEE

Tags: apache, tomcat, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb

when I studied 3-tier architecture, I was told that it takes three servers:
1- web server
2- application server
3- BD server
By cons when I work in JEE, there is a single server that Glassfish or JBOS under which runs all the modules,
My question is how does 3-tiers architecture appear JEE, is it necessary to extract the web module from multi-third party applications and put it specially on a web server, for example apache and leave the EJB on glassfish?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFaEm.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your diagram visualizes application and webcontainer separately but in case of application server, it contains itself web container/server. yes you can use only services which only rely on webserver instead of EJB. So if your specifically talking about java EE then [Distributed Multitiered Applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaay.html) and [What is the difference between application server and web server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936197/what-is-the-difference-between-application-server-and-web-server)

helps you to understand.