# Which Programming languages of web sites development supported by Mongoose Web Server?

Tags: mongoose

I want to use Mongoose Web server, but don't know which language to implement my web site.

Right now considering following languages :

1. Java (*.jsp)
2. Java Servlet
3. Perl via the CGI.pm module (*.cgi, *.ipl, *.pl)
4. PHP (*.php, *.php3, *.php4, *.phtml)
5. Python (*.py) (examples: Pyramid, Flask, Django)
6. Ruby (*.rb, *.rbw) (example: Ruby on Rails)
7. C# (Mono) (.aspx)
8. .NET Core  (ASP.NET MVC) (*.cshtml)

Please let me know which languages are supported from above language list.

Comment: It seems that you're confusing web server and application server. These are two very different responsibilities. I very much doubt that mongoose, the _embedded_ web server can run any of those in your list (except php, and only in its most expensive edition).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thanks a lot.
I have looked into some of the basic concept about Web server and Application Server.
[link]http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077354/learn-java/app-server-web-server-what-s-the-difference.html
[link]
http://www.diffen.com/difference/Application_Server_vs_Web_Server

but, still have doubts. So I found this article:
[link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936197/what-is-the-difference-between-application-server-and-web-server

so, according  to above discussion, Mongoose may be a web server but can support all above languge. right ? If so, then How ?