# What is difference between application server and webserver?

Tags: web-services

What is the actual techincal and functional difference between application server and webserver.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936197/what-is-the-difference-between-application-server-and-web-server

Comment: Simple googling can help for such questions.

Answer (score 1):

Web Server is designed to serve HTTP content. App server can also serve Http Content but is not limited to just HTTP.

Look at the answer marked at below post.

[What is the difference between application server and web server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936197/what-is-the-difference-between-application-server-and-web-server)