# What's the differences between JBoss Web Server and JBoss EAP for running Redhat Decision Manager?

Tags: jboss, drools, jboss-eap-7

I'm researching how to deploy RedHat Decision Manger right now, there are two options for running enviroment, [JBoss Web Server](https://www.redhat.com/en/technologies/jboss-middleware/web-server) and [JBoss EAP](https://www.redhat.com/en/technologies/jboss-middleware/application-platform). But I'm new for JBoss and don't know what's the differences between them and which one is more suitable with Decision Manager for production enviroment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JBoss web server is a server used to deploy web applications, whereas EAP is an application server which can be used also to deploy Java EE compatible applications. EAP gives many more features like messaging, RMI, EJB etc. apart from features provided by Web server.

Which one is better will depend on your use case.

To get more details about the difference between web server and application server refer below post

[Difference between a Web server and application server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936197/what-is-the-difference-between-application-server-and-web-server)