# Is embedded server(MicroServices) equivalent to Application Server(JbossEAP)?

Tags: spring-boot, jboss, microservices

Jboss EAP is full blown application server. Spring boot offers portable embedded server.

is any embedded server(tomcat or jetty) equipped with all the capabilities of a full blown application server?

Is there any areas/cases where embedded server can not work and application server only suits?

My requirement is for future micro service based architecture and i am not interested in legacy applications.

Any differences between micro service deployed in JbossEAP7 vs MicroService runs with its embedded server

Thanks 
-R

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936197/what-is-the-difference-between-application-server-and-web-server

Comment: i understand the diff between application server and web server. if Spring boot offers only embedded web server, it lacks of all the capabilities of application server. right? does it mean spring boot embedded servers only for development phase and not for Production deployment?

Comment: Embedded Tomcat is perfectly suitable for production deployments, because it's just Tomcat that used in thousands of production deployments already.