# HTTP request/response : Port 80 to Port 8085

Tags: tomcat, portforwarding

Hiii,

We all know that when we send a request to sever over http it will send the request to port 80 on the server.however, my spring boot application is running in port 8085. My questions are #1. how does the request is processed when sent to port 80.what do u call the application that is handling incoming   http/s request and what do u call the application running on port 8085.like application server or web server

Answer (score 1):

In these days you can use they interchangeably, but if you want more detail you can check this ***[LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936197/what-is-the-difference-between-application-server-and-web-server)***, and about your first question, the requests receive sync on the server so server receives them in 80 port and will change that to other threads and other ports.