# Do I need to use Apache in my AWS EC2 instance for my flask App?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, flask, amazon-ec2, gunicorn

I'm so confused as to what **benefits** I will be getting from using `Apache` to serve my `Flask App` in my `EC2 instance` if it's already out there to the public, & whether I have to think about using something like Apache or Nginx from the first place?

Why not just configure a production server like `gunicorn` (as I heard it's better to be used for security purposes even though [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/331256/why-do-i-need-nginx-and-something-like-gunicorn#:%7E:text=nginx%20basically%20buffers%20all%20the,pass%20the%20request%20to%20application.) answer kinda made me doubt this a bit) and get a private domain and that's it for my flask app?

Comment: you should focus more your question, are you asking is if possible to run a Flask App  in AWS EC2  using `gunicorn`  **and avoid** using Apache?

Comment: something along these lines as is it recommended ? or what benefits do I get from that? @Oleksii Donoha answer is great

Comment: I don't know why you got all those dislikes but that's indeed a helpful Question.
at least for us beginners

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question boils down to "application server vs web server". In your case gunicorn is an app server, and nginx/apache is a web server.

[What is the difference between application server and web server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936197/what-is-the-difference-between-application-server-and-web-server)

To give some brief advice, you need to consider the scale and actual functionality of your app. If you expect to serve any consistent number of users, use web server, they are better optimized to serve concurrent requests. If your app serves some static files - also use web server, they do it more efficiently. If it's an internal app which only you and couple of guys use occasionally, you can get by only running a gunicorn.