# How to install Tomcat on Apache HTTP Server

Tags: apache, tomcat, war, geoserver

I am playing around GeoServer and I have a Apache HTTP Server
I want to put GeoServer on my Apache HTTP Server, but we can only download a WAR file of GeoServer for Tomcat.

Is it possible to install Tomcat on Apache HTTP server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Tomcat has nothing to do with Apache HTTP Server. If you are trying to deploy some java webapps with JSPs and Servlets (and may be other web framework that uses these two) you just need to install tomcat server only. You can download it from [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi).

If you want to know the difference b/w Tomcat and HTTP server its given [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30632/difference-between-the-apache-http-server-and-apache-tomcat)

Hope this is useful. If any mistakes pardon me.

Answer (score 2):

Tomcat is seperate product which has nothing to do with the Apache Web Server and has to be installed separately,