# Is it possible to install rApache on tomcat 6.0?

Tags: r, tomcat, apache2, rapache

I've followed all over the instruction provided in the below website.

**[rApache.net](http://rapache.net/manual.html)**.

`mod_R.so` is installed and I've configured below things in the `sites-enabled` folder.

```
    #rApacheInfo
    <Location /RApacheInfo>
            SetHandler r-info
    </Location>

    #brew function
    <Directory /var/www/brew>
            SetHandler r-script
            RHandler sys.source
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/brew>
            SetHandler r-script
            RHandler brew::brew
            DefaultType html
    </Directory>
```

But if i go to `localhost:8080/RApacheInfo` I get the error `HTTP Status 404 - /RApacheInfo`.

`localhost:8080` gives me apache tomcat welcome note.

As I checked the differed between `apache` and `tomcat` from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30632/difference-between-the-apache-http-server-and-apache-tomcat). Now I have a doubt whether we'll be able to install it or not.

Please help.

Comment: I think you can let both run if you specify a different port where they will listen to. You should look at the message you receive when starting up apache. It will probably have told you that it did not start up as the port was already used by Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Errr no. Apache tomcat is a server which acts as a container for Java-based 'servlets'. Apache http server is a general server for http requests. What you have listening on port 8080 must be tomcat since you get the tomcat error page.

rApache is specifically a handler for the apache http server. Normally apache http server just sends back a file when a request for /foo.html comes in, but it can be configured to run a program via a handler, which is what rApache is.

You can run apache http server AND tomcat on the same machine, they just have to be listening on different ports. If you try and run them on the same port the second one won't start.

By default apache http server listens on port 80, so if you are running it as root then going to `http://localhost/` will get a response if it is running.

Comment: There's another `nginx` server installed on the same machine. So if I go to `localhost` it's getting directed to `nginx` server. How can I change the port of `apache2` in my case. I'll even try to googling it.