# How to find Apache HTTP Server inside Tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I want to enable caching for httpserver. For this I read some article which say to control Html meta tag with cache-control option. It is fine for and it can be done easily. But further article says to config the apache server. For reference see this link 'https://docs.fastly.com/guides/tutorials/cache-control-tutorial'.
Now My question in this article there is one term call Apache Config, and I am using apache-tomcat for deployment. where is Apache config file in tomcat or is there any other way to config this.

Comment: I believe that article is taking about [apache webserver](http://httpd.apache.org/) ,you will need to route your request from webserver to tomcat. Check this question to understand [difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30632/difference-between-the-apache-http-server-and-apache-tomcat?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache Config in the above tutorial refers to configuration of the [Apache HTTP Server](https://httpd.apache.org). Apache HTTP Server and Apache Tomcat is two different projects. To configure `Expires` and `max-age` of `Cache-Control` header in Apache Tomcat refer to this documentation of the [ExpiresFilter](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/filter.html#Expires_Filter)

Comment: one more question. If I config the ExpriesFilter into tomcat and not use any cache-control in html page. will caching will work?