# Deploying WAR file on LAMP

Tags: java

Can I deploy a Java based web app (WAR file) in the apache server that comes by default with Linux Lamp server installation or do I need to install Tomcat on Linux Ubuntu server and then deploy the WAR?

Comment: You definitely need to instal the JDK and then some sort of container.  Maybe Tomcat, maybe JBoss/Wildfly, maybe something else depending on your requirements.

Comment: You're going to have a hard time running Java on LAMP (Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP).  You need a servlet container such as Tomcat, JBoss, etc.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR

**NO, it will not work with just [LAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29)**

Apache HTTPD which is part of standart LAMP stack is plain web server, where WAR deployment requires [servlet container](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_container).
See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30632/difference-between-the-apache-http-server-and-apache-tomcat)