# Reaching apache tomcat server from browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, tomcat

I am using a AWS server with Ubuntu, Apache tomcat7, Mysql and Java stack. I have prepared a sample dynamic web java application code and deployed on this AWS tomcat server and i can access the webpage through myip:8080 from any browser. My question is i want to access the webpage without entering the port number. i.e., just by entering the ip address in the browser without the port number. Can you let me know how to access the webpage by entering only the ip in the browser

Comment: [The Apache Tomcat Connectors - Common HowTo](https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/common_howto/proxy.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either put your tomcat behind a web server like apache or you can change your tomcats port. The default port for HTTP is 80 and HTTPS is 443. If you don't want to enter an extra port you need to change your server to answer on these ports.

I found a guide configuring [Tomcat AJP with Apache](http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/configure-mod_proxy_ajp-with-tomcat/start) if you want to run an extra web server in front of it.

For changing the port you can checkout other questions and answers e.g. [How to change the port of Tomcat from 8080 to 80?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4758356/1022141). You basically go to the `server.xml` and change the `Port` under `Connector` from `8080` to `80`.

[Difference between the Apache HTTP Server and Apache Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30632/difference-between-the-apache-http-server-and-apache-tomcat?rq=1) elaborates on the differences of the two options.

Comment: Thanks for the links, it was a great help. i have installed tomcat on my local ubuntu. i have eclipse ide and built a sample web application i am able to run it through ide on tomcat server. I can access the url localhost:8080/myapp/ from browser. But i want to access it by just giving localhost:8080/. I have prepared a war file for it and put it in webapp/Root directory of tomcat installation file. but still unable to access it using localhost:8080/. Can you please guide me where i have to put the war file to access it using localhost:8080