# Cannot import java.sql. into localhost

Tags: java, apache, jsp, import

I am trying to make a visitor counter that uses an SQL database to store the number. I am writing JSP to do so. I am using an Apache httpd server that hosts my localhost. I am trying to store the number and will need an import to java.sql. I was told that this will do the import.

```
<html>
<% page import = "java.sql*." %>
<head>
```

Google Chrome's inspect gave me this.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

I have tried putting `<script>` marks in the ends and putting it in the first line. Neither worked.

I don't understand, nor how this happened. Please help.
Also, I'm quite a beginner for this, please forgive.

Comment: The syntax is incorrect, and 'import ... into localhost' is meaningless.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you writing a JSP?

Comment: Yes. I am writing JSP.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to import all classes in package you should add `*` sign after the dot. Because you can't import multiple packages in single statement:

```
  <%@  page import = "java.sql.*" %>
```

Also if you use only few classes inside package consider importing only them, for example:

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.ResultSet" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.Statement" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.Connection" %>
```

Comment: Maybe you have other lines with errors? can you should more of your code?

Comment: But previous line effect this error. Please add previous lines

Comment: Added the previous lines, why do they matter?

Comment: How do you call your JSP?

Comment: test.jsp is the name.

Comment: I think you need apache tomcat, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30632/difference-between-the-apache-http-server-and-apache-tomcat