# How to deploy my NodeJs REST web service on free web hosting like 000webhost.com/?

Tags: node.js, rest, web-services, webserver, webdeploy

I've built an application that runs with node.js, which permits retrieval of data through a REST API.

I want to publish it online on free web hosting like 000webhost.com/   , but I dont know what to do to make my web Service available online.

Can someone explain me the steps to do it?

Answer (score 3):

First you need to understand the difference between a http server and a runtime container. You can learn from this post [Difference between the Apache HTTP Server and Apache Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30632/difference-between-the-apache-http-server-and-apache-tomcat)

Most of the free website hosts are just http server. But some of them supports build-in PHP runtime like Wordpress. Not many of them provides build-in node runtime.

If you wanna to deploy your Node.js server in one click. You can try some PaaS solution like

- [Heroku Quickstart Node.js](https://www.heroku.com/nodejs)
- [Bluemix Quickstart Node.js](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/runtimes/nodejs/getting-started.html#getting-started-tutorial)
- [Azure Quickstart Node.js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-nodejs)

If you want more freedom, you can setup a instance from IaaS like AWS. Here is the [AWS Quickstart Node.js](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-up-node-on-ec2-instance.html). This needs a basic knowledge about Linux.

You need to startup a node runtime in your server for product usage. You better choose a production runtime like [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2)

Answer (score 2):

The free hosting on those websites is mostly for PHP apps. For Node.js, you should go with -

1. [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/nodejs)
2. [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/)

You can host your application for free here. On AWS you have to add your card details to use it for free for one month.